# unable to get asp listView selected item index

Tags: c#, listview

i am trying to set value on listView label. But listview apply value on all label.

```
<asp:ListView ID="productListView" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="selection">
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="lblShowTag">BRAND:</asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server" CssClass="branddrop" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true"> </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblShowTag" text="PRICE: " CssClass="lblShowTag"/><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEachPrice" CssClass="lblEachPrice"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotalPrice" CssClass="lblEachPrice" ForeColor="Green" Text="5000"/>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlBrand" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
<h3>Sorry...No Product Availabel</h3>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

`C#` Code:

**First Approach.** it only apply value on 0 index.

```
 public void ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;


        Label lbl = productListView.Items[index:0].FindControl("lblEachPrice") as Label;
        lbl.Text = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

**2nd Approach:** Apply Selected Value on All Items:

```
public void ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

    foreach (ListViewItem item in productListView.Items)
    {
        Label lbl = item.FindControl("lblEachPrice") as Label;
        lbl.Text = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

i want to set Selected DropDownVaue on Selected ListView or on Click ListView Not All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
public void ddlBrand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)(ddl.NamingContainer);
    Label lbl = item.FindControl("lblEachPrice") as Label;
    lbl.Text = ddl.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lots i was stuck sins 4 to 5 days. you solve my problem. Can you explain me how its work. what actually naming control work with **ddl** and how **Label** knows about this. again Thanks a lot Sir.. :)

Comment: I only know that the NamingContainer property can be used to retrieve the item that contains the control (ddl, in this case), in a GridView or a ListView. More details can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx.